# Capturing RaisePropertyChanged from MVVM Light?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I currently have a Model with a boolean property that stores a checkbox value. When this value changes(checked/unchecked) I want to show or hide a textbox.

Now my Visibility property for the textbox is in my ViewModel and not in my Model. I am not sure how to tell my Visibility property that it should show/hide because the value of the checkbox changed.

I know in all the properties I have RaisePropertyChanged and I thinking this would be something I could use but I don't know how to capture it in my ViewModel.

Or am I approaching this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ViewModel should act as a gate between your Model and your View. It looks like your checkbox is bound directly to the model. It should be bound to the corresponding View Model property that would act as a conduct to the appropriate value to your model. For example (disclaimer: I haven't used MVVM Light, but it should be self explanatory for most MVVM frameworks):

```
public class Chobo2
{
    public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
}

public class Chobo2ViewModel // Your base class and interfaces
{
    private Chobo2 model;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return model.IsChecked; }
        set 
        {
            if(model.IsChecked == value) return;

            model.IsChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Visibility");
        }
    }

    public System.Windows.Visibility Visibility
    {
        get 
        { 
            return IsChecked 
                       ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
                       : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

If your model itself implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and changing your view model logic isn't an option (IE your view directly binds to the model's property), all you can do is listen to the change on the `PropertyChanged` event.

```
// Assume the Chobo2 class implements INPC
public class Chobo2ViewModel // Your base class and interfaces
{
    private Chobo2 model;

    public Chobo2ViewModel(Chobo2 model)
    {
        // Should check for null here
        this.model = model;
        this.model.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => 
            {
                if(args.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Visibility")
            }
    }

    public System.Windows.Visibility Visibility
    {
        get 
        { 
            return model.IsChecked 
                       ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
                       : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am kinda confused of where Chobo2 Model is coming from in the Constructor. I saw that in the MVVM Light video I was just watching, Yes your looks pretty similar to what the video shows but unless I misunderstood something the Creator of MVVM light likes to just bind from the model in such a case I shown to avoid duplicates. You can see this video http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03 around 9mins.

Comment: If you bind directly your view to the model, your view model needs to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event (the model in the constructor was for a contrived short example). Or use a value converter on your view ([`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) comes to mind).